# My Kichler 60" Ferron DC Ceiling Fan does not work after a short

Tags: repair, ceiling-fan, electric-motor

I had some remodeling going on that included electrical work.  In another room I found a GFI plug that failed.  I don't know if that is directly involved or not but the ceiling fan is on this circuit.

I replaced the GFI and everything works again except the ceiling fan.  I tested, and there is power getting to the fan, but it will not turn on.  I have not started beyond this, but my decision tree is:

1. After reading another post I will see if the remote can be resynchronized.  That would be the easiest answer.
2. I don't remember, but if there is a receiver that is separate from the fan but in the hanging system, I will see if I can test or reorder.
3. If all else fails I will open the fan housing.  If there is some type of transformer I will try to replace.
4. If the motor can be removed I will try to remove and replace.

I know this is quite a few steps, but it is a nice fan that was expensive.

Any other thoughts of things I should look at/for?

Comment: Does the fan have any switches like pullchain speed selectors? Is the fan's capacitor serviceable? These may all be handled by a remote receiver unit, but if you can access them you should test them. If not, try to test or replace the remote receiver unit.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  There is not a pull chain.  Your response about the capacitator is appreciated.  I will add that to the algorithm I am going to use to troubleshoot..  To be honest, I am going to have to look up what the capacitator looks like.